# iPhone @2x design in Sketch TROUBLE

Tags: ios, iphone, screen-resolution, sketch-3

I have already read a huge amount of posts and articles about iPhone screen sizes but can't find the info about next problem.

Recently i get a design made in sketch and artboard sizes are 640x1136 (and all the resources are so, like background image). As i can understand - designer heave made a design for iphone 5 - 4inch. And my designs are at 2x. Am i right?

[Please see Sketch project Screen here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs5pH.png)

So i want to export design for all iphones 4,5,6,6s plus.

Currently I'm developing my project with iphone 6s plus physical device.

But when i export designs in sketch as on a screenshoot - i get 3 images

1. 320x568 px (exported as 0.5x)
2. 640x1136 px (exported as 1x)
3. 960x1704 px (exported as 1.5x)

And they doesn't fit for all devices when i add 3 images to Assets.xcassets.

Also i can export at 2x but i get 1280×2272px and it is **bigger** than iPhone 6s plus screen resolution.

What should i do to make this sketch designs work well on all iPhones, especially on my iPhone 6s plus? Maybe i can use only one image for all iPhones in xcode?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about using graphic design software, not programming.

Comment: Agreed. You should move this to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spacemonkey Sorry i can't do that by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are running into is that not all iPhone's have the same aspect ratio. Therefore, you can't simply scale the images to fit to all iPhones.

640 x 1136 is the right pixel resolution for the iPhone 5. However the iPhone 4 is 640 x 960 (shorter in height, but same width).

Depending on what the image is of (and therefore what looks better), you could either crop the images while exporting from Sketch, or stretch the image to fit all screen sizes.

Comment: This is correct. Your designer needs to do two different layouts. One for iPhone 4 and then one for iPhone 5/6/6P. And no, you can't leave out the iPhone 4. If Apple still supports it you have to support it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! So i can export my images as 1x - it will be 640 x 1136 and i will give the suffix to it @2x it will be perfect for iPhone 5. But how about iPhone 6? it is 750 x 1334 px. How can i get such size from sketch or it doesn't meter and iPhone 6 will use @2x?

And if i export as 2x - i get 1280×2272px which is not iPhone 6s plus.
How should i export images to get the right sizes?

Comment: There is no export setting that will give you the right size. The actual graphics must be redesigned in the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: @spacemonkey so i can export images for iPhone5 only?
Thank you for answer, anyway!

Comment: iPhone 5/6 are the same. 6 Plus might be different. It's really the iPhone 4 that you'll have to do some heavy redesign for if you have a tight layout.

Comment: @spacemonkey Ok, got it! Thanks for your help!